# Session comes with multiple details

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a session and session come with User & his roles ( Multiple roles ).I want to show his name.But in my problem that user comes with three roles know,

User 1  - Role 1
User 1  - Role 2
User 1 -  Role 3

Actually in here username(User 1) name duplicated.When it comes 3 roles per user username also shows 3 times.

My Code

```
 @if (Session["UserAndRolesList"] != null)
            { 
                foreach (var user in Session["UserAndRolesList"] as List<NMS.User.Entities.DTO.UserRole>)
                {
                  <span> Hello! @user.FirstName</span> // If user has three roles in this firstname shows 3 times.I want to show this name only 1 time.
                }
            }
            else
            {
              <span>Hello! Gust user</span>
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Session["UserAndRolesList"]` has a list of roles, you can just take and show the first one (if it exists):

```
@if (Session["UserAndRolesList"] != null)
{ 
    var firstRole = (Session["UserAndRolesList"] as List<NMS.User.Entities.DTO.UserRole>).FirstOrDefault();
    if(firstRole!=null)
    {
        <span> Hello! @firstRole.FirstName</span>
    }
}
else
{
    <span>Hello! Gust user</span>
}
```